# Static files are not fetching in django

Tags: javascript, python, css, django

My settings description.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/css')
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

Also, I had added static files to urls.py `urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()`

My HTML template

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Things I eat</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Hello world</h1>
</body>
```

`findstatic` command output:

```
> python manage.py findstatic styles.css
Found 'styles.css' here:
  /project_name/static/css/styles.css
```

I use `django == 3.0.7`

I followed advice from similar questions [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16389989/static-files-are-not-loaded-in-django),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49514132/django-static-files-are-not-loaded),[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39125963/django-static-files-not-fetching-in-heroku)
But my static files are not fetching while rendering.
Any advice for debugging?

EDIT:
My static dir structure:

```
static
-- css
---- styles.css
```

Comment: do you have DEBUG=True in your settings.py?

Comment: yes, but toggling DEBUG=False didn't help either

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same problems and tried many solution but at the end for me below approach worked, I hope it will also work for you

first of all no need to add `STATICFILES_DIRS` and `STATIC_ROOT`

settings.py

```
DEBUG = True

//make sure that django.contrib.staticfiles is present in your installed apps

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

//add this line at the end
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

and seems like you have load static but not added any css file, for that add below line in your html page header

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}">
```

Comment: Thanks! 
Yeah, I didn't add any CSS file to the page header.

Comment: But still seems to face some problems with the path to my css. "GET /static/css/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1782

Comment: btw, why STATICFILES_DIRS and STATIC_ROOT are obsolete?

Comment: Your project will probably also have static assets that aren’t tied to a particular app. In addition to using a static/ directory inside your apps, you can define a list of directories (STATICFILES_DIRS) in your settings file where Django will also look for static files. reference - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

Comment: have you refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/24200094/8379852 have a look. if still not work then provide the screenshot of your server terminal

Answer (score 0):

Did you include stylesheet link? `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/styles.css ' %}">`

Answer (score 0):

I always give the directory separately and then add the CSS folder later.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")]
```

and then in html file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/addrecord.css' %}">
```

For more info.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/